# ng-repeat is not binding the data

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and trying to work with ng-repeat directive example to bind the data to HTML table element.
My js file is located in scripts location where it has a module and controller with some data that is attached to the scope object in that controller.

Now what I want is simply bind that data to my HTML table element and display the data using ng-repeat. I'm using ng-repeat because I have multiple rows to be displayed in the table.

Here is my angular code:

> `

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="angular.js" />



var angularModule = angular.module("TestMyModule", []);
    angularModule.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    var employee  = [
                    {FirstName: "GGG",LastName: "SSS",MiddleName:"G"},
                    {FirstName: "G",LastName: "S",MiddleName: "GG"},
                    {FirstName: "GGS",LastName: "GSS",MiddleName: "GS"},
                    {FirstName: "Go",LastName: "Sa",MiddleName: "Gu"},
                    {FirstName: "Goo",LastName: "SAA",MiddleName: "Gu"}
    ];
    debugger;
    $scope.employee = employee;

});
```

`

Following is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularModule">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="Scripts/AngularExample.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
        <table ng-controller="MyController">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employees in employee">
                    <td>{{employees.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employees.LastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{employees.MiddleName}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the output that I got:

```
 First Name                 Last Name            Middle Name
```

{{employees.FirstName}}  {{employees.LastName}}  {{employees.MiddleName}}

using browser debugger tool, I found the following errors, but not sure how to resolve:

```
AngularExample.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
angular.js:4631 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularModule&p1=Er…20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2785%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A359)
firebug-lite.js:11883 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
firebug-lite.js:30905 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Can someone please help me??

Comment: `ng-app` should be `TestMyModule`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file sequence how you have loaded, angular should have loaded before the `AngularExample.js` in order to load library API available first.

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/AngularExample.js"></script>
```

And ng-app should be `ng-app="TestMyModule"` which is angular module name.

Comment: @user6569407 check out this answer to know [how to accept the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)